# Mageto2: How to change onepage success URL to custom URL?

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

I'm using Magento 2.2.7 with 10+ third party extensions (Amasty checkout, multiinventory etc) and 20+ custom extensions.

How do I change the `checkout/onepage/success` URL to my custom controller, with same design and functionality without affecting native Magento functions and extension functions?

I can change the URL redirect from

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/DefaultConfigProvider.php
```

Does that cause any issues? Please provide some advice.

Comment: no any issue you can create your custom success page via this redirection, but you need to override this model class if i am not wrong

Comment: My question is, Override this model class and clone the onepage success controller is enough?

Comment: yes its enough, if you like it then up-vote my comment

Comment: Post answer with details, I will accept.

Comment: can you please help me to solve this issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/296092/magento-2-how-we-can-apply-those-condition-in-the-frontend.  i will share my package on github